# how to open a certain storyboard view from a today widget using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-today-widget

Hey guys I'm working on an iOS application that has a today widget that when the user hits the camera button it will open the camera app I made within my application via storyboard i've done research and found that you could use URL schemes to do this but I've only found examples in swift and my app is done in Objective-C.

heres the code to the widget:

```
#import "TodayViewController.h"
#import <NotificationCenter/NotificationCenter.h>


@interface TodayViewController () <NCWidgetProviding>

@end

@implementation TodayViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)internetbttn: (id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    [self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:nil];
}

-(IBAction)emailbttn: (id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:"];
    [self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:nil];
}


-(IBAction)itunesstorebttn: (id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/genre/music/id36?mt=8"];
    [self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:nil];
}


-(IBAction)appstorebttn: (id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/genre/mobile-software-applications/id36?mt=8"];
    [self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:nil];
}



-(IBAction)musicbttn: (id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"music://"];
    [self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:nil];
}

-(IBAction)photobttn:(id)sender {

    //This is where the photo button needs to go!

}





- (void)widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NCUpdateResult))completionHandler {
    // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

    // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResultFailed
    // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResultNoData
    // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResultNewData

    completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNewData);
}


@end
```

any ideas on how to do this in Objective-C

Thanks in advance